# cublasSasum causing segmentation fault in custom TensorFlow op

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cuda, cublas

I am trying to implement a custom TensorFlow op using the [cublas](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html) library, but the use of [`cublasSasum`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-asum) is causing a segmenatation fault when integrated into the TensorFlow op kernel.

I have first successfully compiled and tested the `cuda_op_kernel.cpp` example from [head](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/adding_an_op) (compiled using cuda_op_kernel.cpp and cuda_op_kernel.cu.cc). This works fine, and can be imported and used using `tf.load_op_library()` from python.

Secondly I have implemented the op functionality in CUDA, compiled using nvcc and executed it. This code includes both `cublasSasum`, and [`cublasSgemm`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm) operations which compile fine and produce the desired result.

However, when I try to substitute this kernel into the `cuda_op_kernel.cpp` example the op appears to compile fine, but then when imported and used by python it produces a segmentation fault at runtime. There is no additional information provided beyond:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am not sure whether this is a compatibility issue,between cublas and the TensorFlow C++ libraries, because if i remove the `cublasSasum` operation, everything works fine, and `cublasSgemm` produces the desired output.

There are some errors relating to the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library produced during compilation with nvcc, but they occur without `cublasSasum` as well and everything seems to work fine.

**nvcc output:**

```
/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsImpl.h(651): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]"
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igammac_cf_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]" 
(855): here
            instantiation of "Scalar Eigen::internal::igamma_generic_impl<Scalar, mode>::run(Scalar, Scalar) [with Scalar=float, mode=Eigen::internal::VALUE]" 
(2096): here
            instantiation of "Eigen::internal::igamma_retval<Eigen::internal::global_math_functions_filtering_base<Scalar, void>::type>::type Eigen::numext::igamma(const Scalar &, const Scalar &) [with Scalar=float]" 
/home/fg299/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../src/SpecialFunctions/SpecialFunctionsHalf.h(34): here
```

**example producing error:**

stack.cpp

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

using namespace tensorflow;  // NOLINT(build/namespaces)

REGISTER_OP("MyKernel")
    .Input("input: float")
    .Output("output: float");

void MyKernelLauncher(const float* in, const int N, float* out);

class MyKernelOp : public OpKernel 
{
    public:
        explicit MyKernelOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

        void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override 
        {
            // Grab the input tensor and get shapes
            const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
            const TensorShape& input_shape = input_tensor.shape();
            int N = input_shape.dim_size(0)*input_shape.dim_size(1);
            std::cout<<N<<std::endl;

            // get intput as eigen tensor. 
            auto input = input_tensor.flat<float>();

            //Create an output tensor
            Tensor* output_tensor = nullptr;
            // create output shape
            TensorShape output_shape;
            output_shape.AddDim(1);

            // create output tensor
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, output_shape, &output_tensor));
            auto output = output_tensor->flat<float>();

            // call the kernel
            MyKernelLauncher(input.data(), N, output.data());

        }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("MyKernel").Device(DEVICE_GPU), MyKernelOp);
```

stack.cu

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#if GOOGLE_CUDA
#define EIGEN_USE_GPU
#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"

/* main function */
void MyKernelLauncher(const float* d_w1, const int N, float* h_ans)
{

    /* Initialize CUBLAS */
    cublasStatus_t status;
    cublasHandle_t handle;

    status = cublasCreate(&handle);
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "!!!! CUBLAS initialization error\n");
        cudaDeviceReset();
    }

    printf("STARTING SUM\n");
    /* perform cublasSasum*/
    status = cublasSasum(handle, N, d_w1, 1, h_ans);
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("cublasSasum failed\n");
        cudaDeviceReset();
    }
    printf("DONE SUM\n");

    /* remove monitoring handle */
    cublasDestroy(handle);
}

#endif
```

test.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

my_module = tf.load_op_library("./stack.so")
b = np.ones((5,5))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    ans = my_module.my_kernel(b)
    print(ans.eval())
```

**As I mentioned this works fine if I use a different cublas function other than `cublasSasum`.**

Comment: unless your input tensor is on the device and your output tensor is on the host, this won't work.

Comment: Well if my understanding is correct [`cublasSasum`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm) should be able to take pointers to either host or device for its result? (I apologise for the confusing pointer names). But both pointers `d_w1` and `h_ans` are provided by `context`, and while I would assume these would be pointers to device for efficiency, i am not 100% sure.

Comment: A seg fault can be isolated to a specific line of source code, and doing this usually helps with such questions.  Anyway, if it is working for you with `Sgemm`, then I would guess that (both of) your tensors are on the device.  In that case you could try adding `cublasSetPointerMode(handle, CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_DEVICE);` right after the call to `cublasCreate`.  Sasum can send its output either to host or device, but you must tell it where it will go and the supplied pointer must mach your stated location.

Comment: **Solved.** You are a hero. Though I'm still none the wiser as to what the issue was. Was it becasue `status` itself was on host and thus could not be accessed ?